# Accidentally ctrl+d on a folder and now I can't find it

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I was moving pictures from my camera to one of my folders on desktop. While I was doing that I was sorting out pictures so as I moved them to folder I deleted them from my camera and I accidentally pushed ctrl + d(or even ctrl + z) and the folder dissapeared. Now I can't find the folder in the recycle bin or anywhere. How can I restore that folder?

Literally the folder was already full with pictures from last 12 months and I think I accidentally pressed ctrl+z and as it was a new folder it dissapeared.

Comment: Try the Windows File Recovery App from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: CTRL-Z will undo the last action up to where it can. That means, it will move a folder or files back to its previous location after a move command, it will delete files after a copy command and it will delete new files if you right-click new, ... A hard deleted file cannot be undone, obviously. If you copied files from a camera to local, it may have copied them to a temp folder, then moved them into place. The CTRL-Z likely moved it back to temp.

Comment: In the spirit of the comment by @LPChip, go to *Start > Edit the system environment variables > Advanced tab > Environment Variables...* and look in the folders in the TEMP variables in both the upper and lower panes. These folders might contain your files (with a lot of luck).

Comment: @harrymc why not just type %temp% and %tmp% in explorer's addressbar? ;)

Comment: Not in temp folder unfortunately. I don't really understand how could it disappear like that because I renamed the folder to "k" so if I ctrl + z it should undo the name to new folder not remove the folder.

Comment: I also searched the entire c: drive. Not sure how it's possible for folder with hundreds of pictures to disappear.